# Flatbuffers - object API - Array of pointers for efficiency?

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

given the following schema, using object APi in C++,

```
include "link_to_sub.fbs";
namespace My_namespace;


table My_tables {

    list : [ namespace.of.Table ] (required, native_inline);

}

root_type My_tables;
```

In the generated file by `flac`, I end up with a vector of `TableT` in `My_tablesT`, which is expected, defined as:

```
vector<namespace::of::TableT> list{}
```

I would like

```
vector<namespace::of::TableT*> list{}
```

instead, because I already have `TableT` somewhere in memory. That avoids one full copy.

Note: I want to keep using the c++ object api, much easier.

Note2: the context is on-the-fly flatbuffer creation, so they are dynamically created with differing data from already existing sources.

How can I do that, how can I tell flatc to generate a vector of pointers instead ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to create a vector of pointers? What particular problem do you have with that? Anyway, raw pointers are suitable if you do not need to care about the lifetime of those tables managed by some other code. Otherwise, shared pointers, or even a combination of shared and weak pointers might be more appropriate.

Comment: @DanielLangr: My tables are in non modified memory outliving the current block so it's safe to point to. But yes, I would like to tell flatc that I want it to use a vector of pointers instead of real native types. Maybe the custom allocator will help, not sure though

Answer (score 2):

Got it:

```
cpp_ptr_type: "naked"
```

on the field.

Nice.